# Outlook 2010 Add-in - How to determine which MailItem is being shown in the "Reading Pane"

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am trying to write an Add-in for Outlook 2010 that will move emails from my inbox to various archive folders (based on a set of filtering criteria.

My main goal is for all of my new emails to arrive in my inbox and only be moved once they are marked as read and no longer being displayed in the "Reading Pane".

Is there an event handler for when a new mail item is displayed in the "Reading Pane"?

Could one of these interfaces help:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorers
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspectors
Outlook.NavigationPane
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Explorer.SelectionChange` event to see when a particular message is selected (and the old one is deselected).

Answer (score 0):

I used the `Explorer.SelectionChange` event and it did the trick. Here is the code to print the email subject when a new item is selected.

```
    Outlook.Explorer explorer;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();

        explorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(explorer_SelectionChange);
    }

    void explorer_SelectionChange()
    {
        if(0 == Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count)
        {
            // On start up there are no selections so do nothing...
            return;
        }

        // Get the first mail item
        var item = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];

        //
        if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected email's subject: " + ((Outlook.MailItem)item).Subject);
        }
    }
```